# Can't find crate for `num`

Tags: import, rust, rust-crates

I'm trying to use BigUints from the num crate in Rust, and I'm using this code to import them:

```
extern crate num;

use num::bigint::BigUint;
```

However, it returns the following error when I compile:

```
main.rs:1:1: 1:18 error: can't find crate for `num`
main.rs:1 extern crate num;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm not using any compiler flags.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm not using any compiler flags.

If you're using just `rustc`, then you'll need to use flags to grab the num crate

```
$ rustc foo.rs --extern num=/path/to/num.rlib
```

should do it, I think. Of course, you'll have to get a copy of the num crate: https://crates.io/crates/num links to https://github.com/rust-lang/num .

If you use Cargo, you can just add

```
num = "*"
```

To the `[dependencies]` section of `Cargo.toml` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: It’s also possible to use the `-L` flag with `rustc`: `$ rustc foo.rs -L /path/to/libs/`